# Magento product review submition return page

Tags: php, magento

Once a magento product review has been submited it returns be default back to a black review form with a notification message at the top of the page saying it has been submited.

I would rather the page returns back to the original product information page rather than a blank review form.

Is there a way I can change the return page ?

Comment: check "ProductController.php" file in app/code/core/Mage/Review/Controllers" which is available `$this->_redirectReferer();` return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oguz stated,

This is what you're looking for inside "ProductController.php" in app/code/core/Mage/Review/Controllers":

To redirect to the homepage, replace

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

with

```
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().’home’);
```

Remember, that editing core is never a future-proof solution. This will work as a temporary solution.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping there was going to be a more simple solution without having to mod the core,